# CTYPES and PYTHON3: Can't return long string

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have a C++ code for which I created a python.ctypes wrapper. It works quite well, except when the returning string is long. Example of C code:

```
extern "C" {

const char * hallo(char * nome)
{
    string str(nome);
    str = "hallo " + str;

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        str += " new content";

    return str.c_str();
}
```

My python code is:

```
self.lib = ctypes.CDLL(LIB_PATH)
self.lib.hallo.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
self.lib.hallo.argtypes =[ctypes.c_char_p]
j = self.lib.hallo('my name'.encode())
print('INIT: ' + j.decode())
```

The string size is dynamic (in fact, it will be a json string). What is the best way to deal with this situation?

Thanks so much.

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a stack-allocated string object. This is an error - you need to ensure that the content of the char * lasts longer than the lifetime of the routine - e.g. by making `static string str`, and returning the c_str() of that (bearing in mind that the routine will not be thread safe, etc after that).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is that when you `return str.c_str()` you're returning a pointer to stack allocated memory which gets overwritten on return from the C++ code.

Potential workarounds are to use `static string str` such as:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

extern "C" {

const char * hallo(char * nome)
{
    static std::string str;
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << "hallo " << nome;

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        stream << " new content";

    str = stream.str();
    return str.c_str();
}

}
```

Although this will prevent you from calling the routine from multiple threads.

If you want to be able to call it from multiple places, you should probably take a parameter pointer to some memory, and pass in a pointer buffer created from `ctypes.create_string_buffer` (hoping that it has the right size in this case).

For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

extern "C" {

const char * hallo(char * nome, char *writebuffer, unsigned int buffersize)
{
    std::string str(nome);
    str = "hallo " + str;

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        str += " new content";

    if (str.size() < buffersize) {
        str.copy(writebuffer, buffersize);
        return writebuffer;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

}
```

Then some sample python code that uses this library; passing in a 128k buffer (python 3 updated):

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL(LIB_PATH)
lib.hallo.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
lib.hallo.argtypes =[ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_uint]
allocation = ctypes.create_string_buffer(128 * 1024)
j = lib.hallo('my name'.encode(), allocation, 128 * 1024)
if j is not None:
    print('INIT: ' + j.decode("UTF-8"))
else:
    print("Buffer was too small")
```

Comment: Simple types such as `c_char_p` are converted automatically as function results and struct fields, so you can use `j` here instead of `allocation.value`.

Comment: Also, using `CDLL` is preferred. `cdll.LoadLibrary` doesn't let you pass options such as `use_errno`, `mode` or an explicit `handle`. I know some of the tutorial examples use `cdll`, but it's pointless on POSIX systems, and its intended use on Windows is a horrible idea (i.e. sharing function pointer instances globally).