# Decode C const char* in Python with ctypes

Tags: python, c++, c, ctypes

I am using `ctypes` (imported as `c`) in Python 3 to execute a C++ shared library. The library is loaded into python using:

```
smpLib = c.cdll.LoadLibrary(os.getcwd()+os.sep+'libsmpDyn.so')
```

One of the functions has the `extern 'C'` declaration `const char* runSmpModel(...)`. The python function prototype is coded and run as:

```
proto_SMP = c.CFUNCTYPE(c.c_char_p,...)
runSmpModel = proto_SMP(('runSmpModel',smpLib))
res = runSmpModel(...)
```

This all works beautifully, but I'm unable to decode the `res` variable and obtain the string passed out by the C `runSmpModel` function. The value of `res` is displayed (I'm using `ipython3`) as `b'\xd0'`. The best solution I've found online - `res.decode('utf-8')` gives me the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

The `const char*` return value from the `runSmpModel` function comes from

```
std::string scenID = SMPLib::SMPModel::runModel(...);
return scenID.c_str();
```

inside runModel, it is ultimately defined as shown here, where `scenName` is an input string:

```
auto utcBuffId = newChars(500);
sprintf(utcBuffId, "%s_%u", scenName.c_str(), microSeconds); // catenate scenario name & time
uint64_t scenIdhash = (std::hash < std::string>() (utcBuffId)); // hash it

auto hshCode = newChars(100);
sprintf(hshCode, "%032llX", scenIdhash);
scenId = hshCode;
```

The value of this specific `res` should be `0000000000000000BBB00C6CA8B8872E`. How can I decode this string?

After a lot of further testing, I've identified the problem as the length of the string passed from the C function. No problems if the string is up to 15 characters in length, but if it's 16 or longer - no dice.  For a minimum-working example, the C-code is:

```
extern "C" {
  const char* testMeSO()
  {
    string scenarioID = "abcdefghijklmnop";
    return scenarioID.c_str();
  }
}
```

and python code is (same definition of smpLib as shown above):

```
proto_TST = c.CFUNCTYPE(c.c_char_p)
testMeSO = proto_TST(('testMeSO',smpLib))
res = testMeSO()
print("Scenario ID: %s"%res.decode('utf-8'))
```

This gives the decode error, unless any character is removed from the `scenarioID` variable in the C function. So it seems the question is "how can Python read a C `char*` longer than 15 characters, using `ctypes`.

Comment: One byte can't suddenly become 16. You are having a different problem.

Comment: The call returned a pointer to a buffer that starts with `b'\xd0\x00'`. If you really want help, you're going to have to provide documentation for the function -- what it does, what the parameters are, how it behaves when it fails, and so on.

Comment: It doesn't sound reasonable that all that information be required - only the information regarding this return value.  I have edited the question, adding this information.

Comment: You're right, we don't need all that information.  What we need is an [mcve].  Write an equivalent, simplified function that only returns a string in that format (a few lines of C), wrap it in Python ctypes and reproduce your problem.  Post the C and Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several days of debugging and testing, I've finally gotten this working, using the second solution posted by @Petesh [on this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584002/ctypes-and-python3-cant-return-long-string).  I don't understand why `ctypes` is apparently limiting the `char *` value passed from C to 15 characters (+termination = 256 bits?).

Essentially, the solution is to pass into the C function an extra `char * buff` buffer that has already been created using `ctypes.create_string_buffer(32*16)`, as well as an `unsigned int buffsize` of value 32*16. Then, in the C function execute `scenarioID.copy(buff,buffsize)`. The python prototype function is modified in an obvious way.